# Nested attributes saving with empty values rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have two models. order and order has many order_products.
i am using angularjs post request to create an order.
angular controller:

```
return $scope.submitForm = function() {
    var order_products_attributes;
    if ($scope.buyer.selected_item) {
        $scope.order.company_id = $scope.buyer.selected_item.id;
    }
    order_products_attributes = [];
    var qtt = 0
    $scope.op.forEach(function(obj) {
        var newObj;
        var total = parseInt(obj.quantity) * parseInt(obj.batch.selected_item[0].pack_size);
        qtt= qtt+total;
        newObj = {
            product_id: parseInt(obj.product.selected_item[0].id),
            product_batch_id: parseInt(obj.batch.selected_item[0].id),
            price: parseInt(obj.price),
            quantity: parseInt(obj.quantity),
            free_quantity: parseInt(obj.free_quantity),
            total_quantity:total ,
            total_amount: parseInt(obj.total_amount)
        };
        return order_products_attributes.push(newObj);
    });
    $scope.order.order_products_attributes = order_products_attributes;
    $scope.order.price = $scope.amount;
    $scope.order.discount = $scope.discount;
    $scope.order.quantity = qtt;
    $scope.order.status = 'Booked'
    // $scope.order.dc_date = $("#orderDate").find("input").val()
    $scope.order.order_date = $("#orderDate").find("input").val()
    // $scope.order.delivery_date = $("#orderDate").find("input").val()
    $scope.order.delivery_date = $("#deliveryDate").find("input").val()

    var st = $("#orderDate").find("input").val().split("/");
    var dd = new Date(st[2],st[1]-1,st[0]);
    dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+30);
    $scope.order.due_date = dd;

    $scope.order.authenticity_token = $scope.authenticity_token;
    $scope.order.type = type;
    // if($scope.p_type.selected_item)
    //     $scope.order.payment_type = $scope.p_type.selected_item.value;
    console.log($scope.order)


    return $http.post('/orders', $scope.order).then(function(response) {
        response.data;

        $window.location.href = '/orders/invoice_print/'+response.data.id;
    });
};
```

following is the request.

```
Parameters: {"company_id"=>13, "order_products_attributes"=>[{"product_id"=>6, "product_batch_id"=>26, "price"=>1100, "quantity"=>1, "free_quantity"=>nil, "total_quantity"=>10, "total_amount"=>11000}], "price"=>11000, "discount"=>0, "quantity"=>10, "status"=>"Booked", "order_date"=>"13/11/2017", "delivery_date"=>"13/11/2017", "due_date"=>"2017-12-12T19:00:00.000Z", "authenticity_token"=>"OJx5FtSx6+e0FEhlRdUIqzfW7OhA18/Y3B3ETAqye8en3WC49QhR0smmz3MGoqRfsqmckMFLhVsz2ldRnmDXXA==", "type"=>"RegisteredOrder", "order"=>{"company_id"=>13, "price"=>11000, "quantity"=>10, "order_date"=>"13/11/2017", "delivery_date"=>"13/11/2017", "discount"=>0, "type"=>"RegisteredOrder", "due_date"=>"2017-12-12T19:00:00.000Z"}}
```

My models are

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :order_products, inverse_of: :order, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
end
class OrderProduct < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :order
end
```

Controller:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
status_value_id = StatusValue.where(:status_val=> 'Booked').where(:status_type => 'sale-order').first.id
@order.order_products_attributes = params["order_products_attributes"]
@order.save


params.require(:order).permit(:status,:company_id, :type, :price,:quantity,:discount, :order_date, :delivery_date ,:due_date, :dc_date, :dc_number, :order_number, :invoice_number,  :special_instruction,order_products_attributes: [:id,:product_id, :description, :product_batch_id, :quantity,:pack_size,:total_quantity, :price, :discount, :discount_percentage, :total_amount])
```

It creates order products but all attributes are set to null. following is the output. it works perfectly fine in rails 4 but not working in rails 5.

```
INSERT INTO "orders" ("company_id", "price", "quantity", "order_date", "delivery_date", "created_at", "updated_at", "discount", "order_number", "invoice_number", "type", "dc_number", "user_id", "due_date", "status_value_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15) RETURNING "id"  [["company_id", 13], ["price", 11000.0], ["quantity", 10], ["order_date", 2017-11-12 19:00:00 UTC], ["delivery_date", 2017-11-12 19:00:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2017-11-13 06:06:52 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-11-13 06:06:52 UTC], ["discount", 0.0], ["order_number", 26], ["invoice_number", 26], ["type", "RegisteredOrder"], ["dc_number", "10"], ["user_id", 1], ["due_date", 2017-12-12 19:00:00 UTC], ["status_value_id", 9]]
SQL (16.0ms)  INSERT INTO "order_products" ("order_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["order_id", 90], ["created_at", 2017-11-13 06:06:52 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-11-13 06:06:52 UTC]]
```

Comment: the parameters you are getting from angular post request does not contain any `:order` attribute, so requiring it like `params.require(:order).permit(...)` would result in `ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: order`

Comment: also make sure you set the `Content-Type: application/json` header from angular so that the json is parsed into `params` inside `OrdersController`

Comment: that error isn't showing instead order is saving.

Comment: http.post('/orders', $scope.order).then(function(response) {}) 
this is my request.

Comment: can you pls share your original `orders#create` action? so that we can get a clue on how to rewrite it in a way that would handle the strong parameters properly

Comment: that is original.

Comment: the output from `console.log($scope.order)` shows that you have redundant attributes inside of it. e.g. the `order` hash is nested inside the parameters with all the values already included ahead of it.

Comment: can you share the definition of `order_params` that you are calling in the first line of the action `@order = Order.new(order_params)`

Comment: next lines are just for redirection.

Comment: How did you define `order_params`

Comment: that's already given just under order.save

Answer (score 0):

`params["order_products_attributes"]` is not permitted by default. so you have to permit it like:

```
private

def order_products_attributes_params
  params.permit(order_products_attributes: [:product_id, :product_batch_id, :price, :quantity, :free_quantity, :total_quantity, :total_amount])
end
```

and use it while assigning to `@order` and save it like:

```
@order.order_products_attributes = order_products_attributes_params[:order_products_attributes]
@order.save
```

---

Btw the above solution does not act in rails way. It may work anyway. To make it standard, it should look like:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.save # this should create the new :order along with a nested :order_product

# the following should not be needed if you pass the parameters from angular in correct way
# @order.order_products_attributes = order_products_attributes_params[:order_products_attributes]
```

So you should better take care of sending the parameters from angular that would look like:

```
Parameters:
{  
  "authenticity_token": "OJx5FtSx6+e0FEhlRdUIqzfW7OhA18/Y3B3ETAqye8en3WC49QhR0smmz3MGoqRfsqmckMFLhVsz2ldRnmDXXA==",
  "order": {
    "company_id": 13,
    "price": 11000,
    "discount": 0,
    "quantity": 10,
    "status": "Booked",
    "order_date": "13/11/2017",
    "delivery_date": "13/11/2017",
    "due_date": "2017-12-12T19:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "RegisteredOrder",
    "order_products_attributes": [  
      {  
        "product_id": 6,
        "product_batch_id": 26,
        "price": 1100,
        "quantity": 1,
        "free_quantity": nil,
        "total_quantity": 10,
        "total_amount": 11000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`order_params` would look like:

```
private

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:company_id, :price, :discount, :quantity,
     :status, :order_date, :delivery_date, :due_date, :type,
     :order_products_attributes: [
       :product_id, :product_batch_id, :price, :quantity, :free_quantity,
       :total_quantity, :total_amount
     ]
  )
end
```

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: company_id, order_products_attributes, price, discount, quantity, status, order_date, delivery_date, due_date, authenticity_token, type, order

Comment: my bad. edited. pls follow again and update your report

Comment: already trying that. this time giving some type error. let me check that.

Comment: edited with all the nested attributes. now it should work.

Comment: didn't work that with either. then i tried by adding all parameters. now error is "TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)". although i am parsing all values before adding in angular ctrl.

Comment: `didn't work that with either` -- would you pls share the log after following my edit. interested to see what error you are getting

Comment: i commented that before your last comment. after adding all nested attributes i am receiving "TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):" error as i mentioned above.

Comment: it finaly worked with this 
'@order.order_products_attributes = order_products_attributes_params[:order_products_attributes]'
order_products_attributes_params was returning a hash { [ {} , {} ] } so i extracted array of order_products_attributes from that.
BTW thanks.

Comment: yes you are right. i don't know why but my angular controller(given above) sending data that way.

Answer (score 0):

it finally worked with addition of

```
@order.order_products_attributes = order_products_attributes_params[:order_products_attributes]‌​
```

to wasif's answer.

order_products_attributes_params was returning a hash { [ {} , {} ] } so I extracted array of order_products_attributes from that